# SQL Update with COUNT(*) less than 2

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have two tables to query from. An "Order_Details" table and a "Product" table. I need to COUNT(*) the amount of times each product has been ordered(identified by unique a "ORDER_ID"), from the "Order_Details" table. If the amount of times a product has been ordered is less than 2, I need to lower the price by 1 dollar. This is also done from two tables because items that haven't been ordered, also need to have the price lowered. However, those Product_IDs will not show on the "Order_Details" table. I was able to figure out how to select all the products ordered less than 2 times. However, I don't know how to do the same thing, but with updating the price. Here is the SELECT statement I figured out.

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, COUNT(*)
FROM PRODUCT FULL JOIN ORDER_DETAILS
ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_DETAILS.PRODUCT_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way, using correlated subqueries to check if a given product has only one or zero orders.  If so, then we decrement the price by one.

```
UPDATE PRODUCT p
SET PRICE = PRICE - 1
WHERE
    (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(ORDER_ID), 0) FROM ORDER_DETAILS od
     WHERE od.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID) =
    (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(ORDER_ID), 0) FROM ORDER_DETAILS od
     WHERE od.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID);
```

Comment: This should have better performance than the version I propose, but it doesn't generalize so easily beyond "2".

Answer (score 2):

My first thought is a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE PRODUCT p
SET PRICE = PRICE - 1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM ORDER_DETAILS
       WHERE od.PRODUCT_ID = p.PRODUCT_ID
      ) < 2;
```

It is almost a direct translation of your question and generalizes better than Tim's query.  That said, Tim's should have better performance with reasonable indexes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply use an `IN` clause to achieve this by selecting the `PRODUCT_ID` of each product that I wanted to reduce the price of.

The SQL would be something like this (see my note below):

```
UPDATE  PRODUCT
  SET   PRODUCT_PRICE = PRODUCT_PRICE - 1
  WHERE PRODUCT_ID IN (
                      SELECT  PRODUCT_ID
                        FROM  PRODUCT 
                          FULL JOIN ORDER_DETAILS ON PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID = ORDER_DETAILS.PRODUCT_ID
                        HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
                        GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME);
```

Note: Without knowing your schema correctly, I've made assumptions about column names to illustrate how I would approach this.